# How to easily swap Maven settings profiles?

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, nexus

At my company we use a Nexus server to fetch the artifacts. Which is fine. But sometimes I want to use Maven at home too, where I cannot access the company Nexus. Is there an easy way to swap Maven settings profiles? And is it easily swappable with `m2eclipse`?

At the moment I'm using the following settings.xml:

```
<settings
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
      <servers>  
          <server>  
              <id>central</id>  
              <username>company-user</username>  
              <password>company-user</password>  
          </server>  
          <server>  
              <id>mirror</id>  
              <username>company-user</username>  
              <password>company-user</password>  
          </server>  
      </servers>  
      <mirrors>  
        <mirror>  
            <id>mirror</id>  
            <url>https://url.to.company.nexus</url>  
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>  
        </mirror>  
      </mirrors>  
      <profiles>  
          <profile>  
              <id>defaultprofile</id>  
              <repositories>  
                  <repository>  
                      <id>central</id>  
                    <name>Repository for Company artifacts</name>  
                      <url>https://url.to.company.nexus</url>  
                      <releases>  
                          <enabled>true</enabled>  
                    </releases>  
                      <snapshots>  
                          <enabled>true</enabled>  
                    </snapshots>  
                  </repository>  
              </repositories>  
              <pluginRepositories>  
                  <pluginRepository>  
                      <id>central</id>  
                    <name>Repository for Company artifacts</name>  
                      <url>https://url.to.company.nexus</url>  
                      <releases>  
                          <enabled>true</enabled>  
                    </releases>  
                      <snapshots>  
                          <enabled>true</enabled>  
                    </snapshots>  
                  </pluginRepository>  
              </pluginRepositories>  
              <properties>  
                  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>  
              </properties>  
              <activation>  
                  <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>  
              </activation>  
          </profile>  
      </profiles>  
      <activeProfiles>  
          <activeProfile>defaultprofile</activeProfile>  
      </activeProfiles>  
</settings>
```

I know i'll probably have to add a new profile to `http://repo1.maven.org/`, but how to make sure the existing `mirrors` will not complain with timeouts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience it is best to have multiple settings file around and swap them as needed. Either by copying the on top of the existing settings.xml from a differently named file or by using the -s option of the mvn command to specify the settings file. If this is too cumbersome to type all the time you can also make an alias for your mvn command with the different settings files. However that breaks bash completion for Maven, which is why I stick to just copying the settings file around with a script.

The same sort of thing actually applies for swapping context e.g. for Git changing the .gitconfig file around so you can pack all those file changes into a script or into different branches in git or whatever..

In addition it can help to run Nexus locally and just connect to it, and let it in turn proxy all the external repos..

Answer (score 2):

The best i can suggest is to use Git/SVN/ and checkin the settings.xml file and use different branches to separate between company and home. Use either

```
svn switch URL/branches/company
svn switch URL/branches/home
```

or

```
git checkout company
git checkout home
```

A profile will not work cause the mirrorOf part can't be put into a profiles area. Changing in m2e can be done via the configuration dialog. But this might cause inconsistency with the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, mirrors can't be configured in profiles. There's an open [request](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3525) in maven for that. As suggested in JIRA, you could use a script to easily switch between different settings.xml

As for answering to the question in the title : to easily switching between profiles in m2e, I suggest you install [JBoss Tools Maven Profile Manager](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/maven/maven-news-3.3.0.M3.html#itemname1) from this update site : http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/juno/

To enable the same global profile(s) on all your projects :

- in the project explorer view : select all *maven* projects (Ctrl+A)
- hit Ctrl+Alt+P to open the Profile Mgmt wizard and select the profiles you want activated.

This is the equivalent to manually set the active maven profiles in each of your project properties page, which is way more tedious.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the artifacts already downloaded in your local repository then you can use `mvn -o clean compile ...`. This will avoid remote repository lookup.